# Entity Data Model attempting to create database, rather than use existing

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

[image: Error Image]

I cannot figure out why I'm receiving the above error in my ASP.NET MVC site.

Some background, this site has existed and has been working in my DEV environment for several months.  I'm using SQL Server and the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to `Update the Model from the Database'.  Recently, I did some pretty large updates that involved changing a few tables around.  Then I began receiving this error.

What I've tried:

- Clearing browser cache, and using different browsers
- deleting all generated tables in the .EDMX file and re-updating them
- deleteing the .EDMX file entirely and recreating it
- confirming my connection strings (the web.config hasn't been updated at all)
- the server is working fine.  I can use it in all other apps and SSMS
- begging to no one in particular

below is the connection string created:

`<add name="RetailDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Helpers.RetailDB.csdl|res://*/Helpers.RetailDB.ssdl|res://*/Helpers.RetailDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=RetailDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=******;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

I'm sure this is probably something I'm overlooking, but I don't understand why it has decided to start trying to create the database itself.  Please let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: how you dbcontext looks like? anywhere you set to crete new db while there is a change

Comment: Your sql server might have problems.. See the error is saying `The server was not found or not accessible`